Sectoriality of the 1-dimensional Laplace operator in $H^{-1}$
I know how to prove that the 1-dimensional Laplace operator is sectorial in $L^{2}$ with the domain being $H_{0}^{1}\cap H^{2}$. I've been wondering how to prove that it is also sectorial in $H^{-1}$ with the domain being $H_{0}^{1}$ (defined as follows: if $u, v \in H_{0}^{1}$, then $\Delta u (v) = -\int \nabla u \nabla v dx$). In particular, I have very little experience with working in the $H^{-1}$ spaces, so any ideas would be much appreciated.

Large Book, I know, but this could be in „ Analytic Semigroups and Optimal Regularity in Parabolic Problems“ by Lunardi

How you prove it on $L^2$?

@S. Maths for the Lp case see Example 10.1.5 in Analysis in Banach spaces Volume 2
